# Searching and navigating through code in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I work on reality big project. And sometimes i get the need to search for some specific keyword inside A single c# file that has many calls of other functions from other c# file.

So i want to know if there is any easy way that could search for give phrase or keyword inside the current file and inside all the functions that my current file calls to. But not in the entire solution or inside the whole project.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that would do that in vanilla VS or ReSharper. You could probably write your own extension to do it. Someone may have already done so, but requesting external tools and the like is off-topic at SO.

Answer (score 2):

1. For inside the file that's Ctrl+F.
2. Otherwise Code Search in VS2022 is very fast. Normally it's bound to Ctrl+T.

   - [Introducing a New Way to Search Your Code and Visual Studio Features](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-a-new-way-to-search-your-code-and-visual-studio-features/)
   - [Code search in Visual Studio 2022 is about to get much faster](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/code-search-in-visual-studio-is-about-to-get-much-faster/)).
3. There also are the `Go To` options in the context menu that could help:
   [image]

4. Finally, at the top of the editor window you can switch between classes and properties/methods.

---

BTW. You can address the large solution problem by splitting the codbase into multiple smaller solutions that only include parts of the overall code. This has some drawbacks, but overall it works very well in my experience.